# how to save the Binary image data to a image file

Tags: node.js, image, binary, png

I am using node js and made a REST API call to retrieve an image file from a remote server, the call completed, and some data was returned.

```
'�PNG

���
IHDR��(������-��biCCPICC Profile��(�m��K�`Ɵh��g)B� T�6�ɡVP�!��[��i!�/ID
�
�_�RG��UpE�Ypt�h��6jZ�����p�{�!�1=��l�ffa.���
� �A@DDV,���ej�wm������p�o�z����g�×7��ۢ;�Z
```

I saved these data to a PNG file. the file cannot be opened properly.

```
The file “***.png” could not be opened.
It may be damaged or use a file format that Preview doesn’t recognize.
```

the same API call in postman App, it worked fine. and a good image file saved to disk.
I guess it encoding issue. so tried some encoding format binary, utf8, base64, and ascII. all failed.
tried write file with stream fs.createWriteStream(url).write(imageBinary) not work

Answer (score 0):

To save binary image data to an image file in Node.js, you can use the fs.writeFile() method provided by the built-in fs module.

You can use:

```
const fs = require('fs');

// binary image data received from the API call
const imageData = Buffer.from(apiResponseData, 'binary');

// path and filename of the output image file
const filePath = '/path/to/output/image.png';

fs.writeFile(filePath, imageData, (err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('Image saved successfully!');
});
```